# Generator/ accessing a list iterator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

```
def init(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if x is None:
            return []
        if x in xs[:-1]:
            yield x

print(list(init(iter([1,2,3,4])))) # --> [1,2,3]
```

So the initial thought was that to remove the last element of the list we only yield  if
x is in the iterator list but without the last element. Im new to generators could maybe someone give me a better solution or show me how I could access the iterator ?

Comment: Unless you're set on using a generator, the easiest solution would just be slicing: `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; l[:-1]` prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If you really want to use a generator (which I think is the wrong tool for the job), `enumerate`ing the input, then just yielding while the index is one less than the highest index would be the easier way I think. `if x in xs[:-1]` is an **extraordinarily** expensive operation, so I'd avoid that at all costs.

Comment: The `list_iterator` you pass as an argument means that `xs[:-1]` consumes the rest of the iterator before another value can be assigned to `x`, so you effectively terminate the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: If you want to remove the last item of a list: `your_list.pop()`. If really need a generator, `yield your_list.pop(0)` might be handy.

Comment: (Somehow I forgot about `pop`, which, unless you need a new collection is by far the best way. I stick by the rest of my comment though).